# MYSQL Exception Handling in Stored Function with return statement

Tags: mysql, exception

TABLE

```
create table EMP(id int primary key, name varchar(50), contact int(10) unique);
```

I want to write stored function for adding employee which will return 1 if insert command executed successfully, it will return 0 if contact number is repeated.

In Oracle, I write function as follow

```
create or replace function addEMP(eID in int, eName in varchar, eContact in number)
return number as
BEGIN
insert into EMP values(eID, eName, eContact);
return 1;
EXCEPTION
when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then return 0;
END;
```

**Similarly, How can I handle exceptions in MYSQL stored function and return some value?**

In Oracle, I can return a value based on exception.
Eg.

```
create or replace function Function_Name(--Parameter_List--)
return number as
BEGIN
    --Statements...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN exception_1 THEN return 1;
    WHEN exception_2 THEN return 2;
    WHEN exception_3 THEN return 3;
END;
```

**How can I implement same logic in MYSQL stored function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch the errors, use an exit handler

```
create procedure sp_proc(in_id int, in_name varchar(50), in_contact int)
begin

declare exit handler for sqlexception
begin
  select 0;
end;


insert into EMP (id, name, contact) values(in, in_id, in_contact);
select 1;

end
```

To return different value based on the error, use the [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html)-command.

Comment: Does it mean that select 1, or select 0 from MySQL work like return 1, and return 0 in oracle?

Comment: In MySQL, a stored procedure can return zero, one or multiple result sets (table like structure with rows and columns). When you do a select (without "into") the selected result set is returned into the calling program (PHP, Perl, C++ etc.) which can then process the result sets.

Comment: can I use 'return 0' and 'return 1' instead of 'select 0' and 'select 1'?

Comment: A stored procedure returns values as rows and rolumns using the `select`, not by a `return`. To return one rows with two columns you can use `select 0, "No rows inserted";`

Comment: Hosting website with Oracle Database was too costy. Hence I decided to switch to Mysql database. If I copied commands of insert, update, delete etc, to mysql and run it, it works well. I found problem only with stored functions and stored procedures as they have different syntax. You solved my problem. Thank you very much...